# How to get size of inner structure

Tags: c, sizeof

I'm trying to get size of inner structure i.e. `struct B`. But I'm getting compilation error:

> prog.c: In function ‘main’:
>   prog.c:10:53: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
>     printf("%d | %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct A::struct B));

Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
        struct B{};
};

int main() {
    printf("%d | %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct A::struct B));
    return 0;
}
```

Could you suggest that how I can achieve this in C?

**UPDATED**

Answer from [@Jabberwocky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336633/8013471) solves my above problem. But What about following code. This can also be found [here](https://ideone.com/wf0IQn):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
    struct B{};
};

struct B
{};

int main() {
    printf("%d | %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct B), sizeof(struct A::struct B));
    return 0;
}
```

In this case I'm getting compilation error as following:

> prog.c:8:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct B’
>   struct B
>         ^
>   prog.c:5:10: note: originally defined here
>     struct B{};
>            ^
>   prog.c: In function ‘main’:
>   prog.c:12:71: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
>    printf("%d | %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct B), sizeof(struct A::struct B));

Here how I can diffrentiate between `struct B` and `struct A::struct B`

Comment: For the second part of your question, read pmg's answer below. Short answer: you can't.

Comment: There is no `struct A::struct B`. C does not recognize `::` as a valid token; maybe you're thinking of C++?

Comment: @pmg I understand that because that is where I'm getting compilation error. This just to show that _What I wants to do?_. And Thanks!!! for your comment and answer :)

Comment: C cannot fry eggs either ... well ... if you use a busy loop on a poorly insulated computer :-)

Comment: Please do not edit questions to ask new questions. When you have a new question, enter a separate new question. Stack Overflow is not a personal service for you; it is intended to create a durable repository of questions and answers. When future readers find your multiple-question question, it may be difficult for them to figure out which answers were written for your first question and which were written for your second question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I edited the question because it was in same context. I do't wanted to create confusion when I create a new question and it would be treated as _similar question_.

Comment: @cse: Please do not edit questions to ask new questions. When you have a new question, enter a separate new question.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
        struct B{};   // this should not compile anyway in C as C
                      // does not allow empty structs
                      // but this would compile: struct B{int a;};
};

int main() {
    printf("%d | %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct B));
                                           // just write struct B
    return 0;
}
```

Working sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
  int b;
  struct B { int a; };
};

int main() {
  printf("%d | %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct B));
  return 0;
}
```

Possible output on a 32 bit system:

```
8 | 4
```

Comment: `this should not compile anyway in C` C does support nested structs as far as I know?

Comment: @DeiDei yes it does, but C does not allow _empty_ structs and `struct B{}` is clearly empty.

Comment: @cse a standard compliant C compiler would not compile this: Look [here](https://www.godbolt.org/z/uLBQx-). But in C++ it compiles. It's a gnu C extension. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24685483/898348

Comment: @Jabberwocky The provided link is having invalid code as line `printf("%d | %d", sizeof(struct A), sizeof(struct A::struct B));`. This is the line where I'm getting compilation error in my question. To verify _if C compiler supports inner structure_, Change it to `printf("%d ", sizeof(struct A));` and it will compile.

Comment: @cse empty structs are not allowed in standard C, but gnu c (gcc) supports them as an extension.

Comment: @cse -- "To verify _if C compiler supports inner structure_,.... ": you can't verify if a compiler supports something by running code in C. You need to appeal to documentation, since undefined behavior can include the appearance of working code. In this case, while _nested_ structures are supported in C, [empty structures are not, leading to undefined behavior](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p8).

Comment: @DavidBowling and Jabberwocky, Thanks for your comments. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that C support for nested structures is logical only. Each structure exists on its own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct A {                   // same as
    int bar;                 // struct B { int foo };
    struct B { int foo; } b; // struct A { int bar; struct B b; };
};

int main(void) {
    struct A a;
    a.bar = 42;
    a.b.foo = -1;
    printf("a.bar is %d; a.b.foo is %d\n", a.bar, a.b.foo);

    struct B b; /* struct B is visible outside struct A */
    b.foo = 666;
    printf("b.foo - a.bar is %d\n", b.foo - a.bar);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/rHaanj